# How do AppState As WebTemplates.State works (ASP .Net)?

Tags: asp.net, .net

The AppState values can be changed/stored through page requests, when (Page_init ?) and how are they changed?

```
//On some other page
Response.Redirect("mypage.aspx?ID=10")

//On Page_Load of myPage.aspx 
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

Dim id = AppSate("ID").Value //id will equal 10
...
end sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is and how it relates to a problem. Also this code is not written in asp-classic as suggested by the tag.

Comment: I just want to know how it works, it works but i do not like it when i don't understant the mechanic behind.